# How to scale a image on a PySimpleGUIgraph (alternatively: how to put gui elements on top of one another with PySimpleGUI)?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Using [PySimpleGUI](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/) I need to draw bounding boxes on top of an image. Currently I do this by putting everything into a graph with `Graph.DrawRectangle()` and `Graph.DrawImage()` which works perfectly fine. The problem arises if I want to scale the image before drawing it, since the `Graph.DrawImage()` doesn't seem to have a scaling function.

My initial idea was to separate the image out into its own [`Image`](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/#image-element) element, which can be scaled. However I can't find a way to place the graph element on top of the image element. Is this not possible with PySimpleGUI?

Comment: Call `window['-GRAPH-'].send_figure_to_back(figure)` where figure is the value returned by method `window['-GRAPH-'].draw_image`, or call `window['-GRAPH-'].bring_figure_to_front(figure)` where figure is the value returned by method `window['-GRAPH-'].draw_rectangle`.

Comment: Resize your image with `PIL.Image.resize`.

Comment: @JasonYang These functions are clear to me, the problem is, that I can't resize the image in the graph. So as you wrote in the second comment, the only way to do this is by resizing with PIL or another external lib?

Comment: Most of people do it by `PIL.Image.resize`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I did it with pillow :)